# ggplot2 mappings changing when using tidy evaluation and aes() instead of aes_string()

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyeval

I am trying to update some older plot-making code that gives the message:

```
Warning message: `aes_string()` was deprecated in ggplot2 3.0.0. Please use tidy evaluation ideoms with `aes()`
```

When I replace aes_string() with aes() and the unquoting !!, I start getting the message "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale" in unexpected places.

Here is a simplified reproducible example:

```
# Make some test data
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),value=rnorm(100))
xvar <- 'x'
yvar <- 'y'
cvar <- 'value'

# This works, but gives a deprecated warning for use of aes_string()
ggplot(dat,aes_string(x=xvar,y=yvar,color=cvar)) + geom_point() + scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(10))

# This changes the plot to use aes() with !! instead of using aes_string()
# It fails with "Error: Discrete value supplied to continuous scale"
ggplot(dat,aes(x=!!xvar,y=!!yvar,color=!!cvar)) + geom_point() + scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(10))
```

I haven't been able to get to the bottom of what's causing this, but it looks like the mappings themselves are being handled differently in ggplot - with aes_string() the variable names show up with a ~ at the beginning, and with aes() and !! they do not:

```
# Capture each plot so it can be examined
plt_working <- ggplot(dat,aes_string(x=xvar,y=yvar,color=cvar)) + geom_point() + scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(10))
plt_broken <- ggplot(dat,aes(x=!!xvar,y=!!yvar,color=!!cvar)) + geom_point() + scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(10))

summary(plt_working) # The second line says "mapping:  colour = ~value, x = ~x, y = ~y"
summary(plt_broken) # The second line says "mapping:  x = x, y = y, colour = value" (no ~s)
```

What does the ~ mean? In this context it doesn't seem likely to have anything to do with formulas or facets.

Why does this change make the plot code stop working, and what would be the correct way to update the code so it will still work?

Comment: Additional detail: Software versions don't seem to matter - this happens on a Linux system with R 4.2.2/ggplot2 3.4.0, and a MacOS system with R 4.2.0/ggplot2 3.3.6

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The current (as of 2023) preferred method for using strings inside of `aes()` is via ggplot's `.data` object (thank you to Lionel Henry for clarifying the reasoning behind it):

```
xvar <- 'x'
yvar <- 'y'
cvar <- 'value'

ggplot(dat,aes(x = .data[[xvar]], y = .data[[yvar]], color = .data[[cvar]])) + geom_point() + scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(10))
```

Alternately, you can wrap your strings in `sym()`, then use `!!` to unwrap them inside `aes()`:

```
set.seed(1)
dat <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100),y=rnorm(100),value=rnorm(100))
xvar <- sym('x')
yvar <- sym('y')
cvar <- sym('value')

ggplot(dat,aes(x=!!xvar,y=!!yvar,color=!!cvar)) + geom_point() + scale_color_gradientn(colors = rainbow(10))
```

Comment: Thanks! That works, but can I ask why, and why it's necessary? I am not a big tidyverse user, but when I have used other tidyverse things like gather() and pivot_longer() they've worked with !! without needing sym(). How do you know when to use sym() and when not to?

Comment: I agree that it feels inconsistent with other tidyverse functions, but how could it work any other way? By default, `aes()` attempts to evaluate the aesthetic mappings (i.e., `color = value`) as unquoted strings. So to substitute strings here, a layer of quasi quotation must be introduced. You could also substitute strings with a little less typing via the `.data` object, which I've added to the answer.

Comment: Thanks! I'm afraid I'm still not understanding though - how do I know when I should use !! and when I should use !!sym() ? Do I just memorize !!sym() as a special thing to do in aes(), or are there other situations where I might need to do it that way?

Comment: @jdobres is correct regarding the ambiguity of strings in this case. That's the difference between data-masking and tidyselections, only the latter can interpret strings. This difference should be stated in the function documentation and is a fundamental property that affects how to use the argument: in a selection you use `c()` for multiple columns, can match with `starts_with()`, etc.

By the way we now avoid `!!` where we can. We recommend either `all_of()` in selection functions like `pivot_longer()`, and `.data[[my_string]]` in data-masking functions.

Comment: @LionelHenry thank you!! The term "data masking" led me to this: https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/dplyr_data_masking.html which I'm posting for anyone who Googles across this later. I'm still not completely sure why !!sym(xvar) worked, but I think I at least kind of understand why .data[[xvar]] is the preferred way to do it.

Comment: yup understanding metaprogramming and injection of symbols / calls / quosures ended up being too much for most users, which is why we are now focusing on easier patterns in our documentation. If you want to read further, the rlang website also has some documentation: https://rlang.r-lib.org/reference/topic-data-mask-programming.html